# Can we have multiple '/ 'separated vaues in a cell in oracle database? Does it violate any rule?

Tags: sql, oracle, normalization, ddl

Like I need to create a table out of this record then what is the best way to do it?

[image]

Comment: of course, as long as the data type of the column is allowing string values ( varchar2, char, nvarchar2, etc ). I don't know what is the problem in your case

Comment: The problem depends on the use case, but OP did not ask if it is technically possible to do it, but if it violates "rules" and what the best way to normalize the data would be.

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/3404097) This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Obviously, it breaks the first rule of normalisation. Avoiding this exact scenario is pretty much the reason why the relational model was invented in the first place. In practical terms, it limits the validation that is possible when maintaining the data, and it limits the queries that can be used to report or manipulate it. If you can store things in comma-separated lists, do you really need a SQL database at all?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is "it depends, but it is likely that you want to separate the values". Especially if you expect a query like "show me all ip-adresses with a range of /24", you will have to atomize / separate these values.

The long answer to the question "what is the best way to do it" is understanding normalization.

As you tagged your question with "normalization" yourself, you may want to read [this article](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/).

Happy coding.

Answer (score -2):

**Short answer** : Yes. You can

**Long answer** : Oracle doesn't care about what you are storing. As long as the column type is Varchar2 or Clob (for instance) you can store litterally any character you want. The problem is what is the best way for you to handle such data. If you are ok with that format, Oracle will follow.